What are the constraint equations for covariant quantization of supermembrane theory?
I'm self-taught when it comes to string theory, so forgive me if I misspeak a bit here.
As I understand it, in order to quantize string theory covariantly, once we have defined the state space, we introduce the constraints that the only physical states are the ones annihilated by the generators $L_n, G_r$ of the Super-Virasoro algebra for $N,r>0$ as well as $L_0 - 1$ (plus some additional constraints for closed strings).
The question I had is, what is the equivalent procedure for the supermembrane theory? Since the Super-Virasoro algebra is the algebra of a 2D superconformal field theory, does that mean for supermembranes we should require the states to be annihilated by the generators of the 3D superconformal algebra? I.e., if we introduce states of the form $$|ψ> \ = |X_0,X_1,...,X_{10}>,$$ would the relevant constraint equations be something like:
$$M_{μν} |ψ> \ = 0$$
$$P_{μ}  |ψ> \ = 0$$
$$D      |ψ> \ = 0$$
$$K_μ    |ψ> \ = 0$$
$$Q_{αβ} |ψ> \ = 0$$
$$S_{αβ} |ψ> \ = 0$$
for $μ,ν$ ranging over the dimensions of spacetime and $α,β$ ranging over (both dotted and undotted) spinor indices?
I tried to look this up in the literature, but I had trouble finding many papers with general information on supermembranes at all, let alone information about covariant quantization.

See second paragraph https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0201151
